# Reasons for download times to be a lot slower in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm trying to figure out why the download of a JS file when loading a page in Chrome is a lot slower than Safari and Firefox on desktop. I've done many page reloads and see that this is consistently the case. The JS file transfer size and decompressed size is showing as the same (242 kb). However, the "Content Download" time would be from 1.3 secs to 2.5 secs while the "receiving" section in Firefox would be from about 30 to 60 ms. I am doing hard reloads with (command + shift + r) on mac for both cases with the disabled cache checked. The loading and painting of the page is indeed slower as expected in the Chrome case.

When I download just the JS file directly (from the CDN) the FF time wouold be about the same and the Chrome "content download" would be a lot lower, about 110 - 140 ms, but still a lot longer than in the FF.

Why is this happening? What are some likely causes of this? How can I make the download time of the JS file in the Chrome browser match that of the Firefox browser?

---

EDIT: I found that even when I cache my resource and the "size" shows as "disk cache", the request still takes over a second! Also, when I click on "replay XHR", the content download time is fast!

I'm also guessing that the more concurrent downloads, in this case in http/2 (up to 6), the slower the content download time would be for each downloaded resource?

---

### EDIT2: I think the problem may be because for whatever reason Chrome sucks at inflating br versus gzip. I noticed that in the responses with `content-encoding` header of `br` had the long `content download` times.

EDIT3: Actually looking at the Chrome Devtools Performance graph, looks like for whatever reason the CPU is more maxed out than in Firefox. Seems like for now the solution is to preload the culprit network request and see if having it download earlier when less CPU resources are being used will make the whole page load process faster.

Comment: Do you have any extensions on your Chrome browser? Even if not, try loading the page with DevTools closed & in an Incognito window to see if you have the same issue.

Comment: @EGC I have a few like rulers and adblocker. I can't test this now but will disable the adblocker and try that. It didn't work in incognito mode but I haven't tried with devtools closed.

Comment: @EGC None of the proposed solutions seem to work, but thanks.

Comment: A lot of people would suggest just uninstalling/reinstalling Chrome. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Otherwise, there's a pretty big list of troubleshooting steps here: https://www.webnots.com/fix-slow-page-loading-issue-in-google-chrome/

Comment: I tried some of the obvious things from those links. However, I updated the problem with 2 more insights/clues.

Comment: Maybe, with the multiple downloads thing; try this? `No, you need to switch on this feature called parallel download in chrome://flags, this will increase the speed of chrome downloading things, because it will share the work load between google servers and download the file a lot quicker.` as per [Reddit Chrome Slow Download](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/8hfwex/why_chrome_downloads_so_slow/)

Comment: Plus the reason it would be quick when you click `replay XHR` is because it's probably already downloaded in Chrome's cache'd memory, and you're just prompting it to download onto YOUR PC? I'd assume: [Secrets of XHR](http://devtoolsecrets.com/secret/performance-replay-a-xhr-network-request.html)

Comment: @EGC, I added an extra edit that it seems to be due to the content encoding. The multiple downloads explanation didn't account well for why it was so much faster with Firefox and other browsers/methods. Both FF and Chrome had the same max of 6 concurrent requests per server. However, it may be that FF has its equivalent turned on by default? Nevertheless I am trying this anyways (need to relaunch browser). Thanks!

Comment: @EGC Yup, still slow.

Comment: Maybe go ask these guys: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev